# How to download GenyMotion 2.3.0

Tags: firefox

When I opened up GenyMotion, it said that a new version of GenyMotion is available 2.3.0 and had a link to download it. When I clicked on the link, it opened up my FireFox browser and gave me this prompt:

[image]

I then proceeded to save the binary file and open it in my browser. When I tried to start the executable, I got another prompt saying the application "is not a valid Win32 application". How do I download this update then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the file from the original site and then run it:
http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.3.0/genymotion-2.3.0.exe